# Прописание прототипных методов непосредственно внутри класса JS

Tags: javascript

Если прописывать «Function Expression» прототипного метода Класса таким образом:

```
function Tag(node="div") {
    if (typeof node !== "string") {
        throw new Error('the given node is not String');
    }
    this.nodeEl = document.createElement(node);
}

Tag.prototype.addClass = function(className) {
    if (!className || typeof className !== "string") {
        throw new Error('no given className or not String type');
    }
    if (~className.indexOf(' ')) {
        (className.split(" ")).forEach((cls) => {
            this.nodeEl.classList.add(cls);
        })
    } else {
        this.nodeEl.classList.add(className);
    }
};

Tag.prototype.placeIn = function (parent) {
    if (parent && parent.parentNode) {
        parent.appendChild(this.nodeEl);
    } else throw new Error("given Parent is not in DOM or not given");
};
```

То лишь после инициализации метода я могу им пользоваться и прописывать что-то такое:

```
const container = new Tag();
container.addClass("flex-box center");
container.placeIn(plate);
```

Отсюда приходиться рабочий код прописывать ниже по коду, а хотелось бы внизу держать все функции с *initial data*., а вверху - рабочий код. Можно, конечно, сверху кода подключать функции с других файлов, но можно пробовать прописывать прототипные методы Класса непосредственно в Классе, примерно так:

```
function Tag(node="div") {
    if (typeof node !== "string") {
        throw new Error('the given node is not String');
    }
    this.nodeEl = document.createElement(node);

Tag.prototype.placeIn = function (parent) {
    if (parent && parent.parentNode) {
        parent.appendChild(this.nodeEl);
    } else throw new Error("given Parent is not in DOM or not given");
};
}
```

Это, конечно, перепрописывает методы при каждой инициализации экземпляров, но дает удобство в размещении рабочего кода над initial data...(ведь все находится в *Function Declaration*)...

Подскажите пожалуйста, что такого плохого происходит, кроме того, что прототипные методы перепрописываются Конструктором при каждом экземпляре?

Этот код не имеет особого практического преимущества над уже существующими практиками. Конечно, можно просто подключать внешние файлы, инициируя Конструктор сверху над рабочим кодом. Вопрос чисто теоретический, связанный, скорее, с механикой работы прототипных функций, а не с практическим применением...

Comment: Это ересь какая-то. Я так и не понял в чем вы видите проблему в первом коде

Comment: Вообще человечество вроде уже умеет пользоваться несколькими файлами, так что декларацию и использование можно просто писать в разных файлах. А ещё человечество придумало умные редакторы кода в которых можно сворачивать блоки. В общем, не нужно решать проблему которая решается выбором адекватного инструмента пытаться решать ухудшением кода.

Comment: Вопрос чисто технический: ЧТО ПЛОХОГО ПРОИСХОДИТ ПРИ ПРОПИСЫВАНИИ ПРОТОТИПНОЙ ФУНКЦИИ НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННО В КОНСТРУКТОРЕ??? Кроме того, что она перепрописывается на каждом экземпляре....
Это лишь теоретические размышления: все равно, как работа с типами данных без использования встроенных методов... :)

Comment: Речь ведь идет не в шаблонном мышлении, умных редакторах и best practices: человечество придумало множество всего полезного... Перейдя на готовые библиотеки и др.инструменты имеется риск позабыть синтаксис и природу вещей вообще...
Отсюда и ставится такая задача: как прописать Конструктор с прототипными методами ПОД РАБОЧИМ КОДОМ, не подключая внешних файлов... извините, Alexey Ten, что запутал Вас...

Comment: Тем более, что можно тогда добираться до приватного свойства Класса:

**function Smth() {
        const SOME = 1000;        
        Smth.prototype.getSome = function () {
            return SOME;
        };
    }
    const smth = new Smth();
    console.log("smth: " + smth.getSome()); **

Можно приватное свойство и в prototype держать... но вроде, в прототайпе принято держать методы, а не свойства. 
Есть, конечно, и статика...